# Xamarin forms: Device.OpenUri is not working for opening pdf in iPhone

Tags: ios, pdf, xamarin.forms

I am using `Device.OpenUri` for opening pdf files in my application. This is working fine on android devices but on iPhone, this is not working. Following is my code:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mypdfurl"));
```

**Following is the screenshot on iPhone when opening pdf.**

[image]

**For opening pdf on iPhone should I add any permissions? Are there any free NuGet packages for showing the pdf in the app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly open the pdf file on the **WebView** . In this way you need to use **Custom Renderer** on Android because Webview in Android doesn't support open remote pdf in default .

#### in code behind

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace PdfLoader
{
    public class PdfWebView:WebView
    {
       public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
       returnType: typeof(string),
       declaringType: typeof(PdfWebView),
       defaultValue: default(string));

        public string Uri
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

#### in Android

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using PdfLoader.Droid;
using PdfLoader;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PdfWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace PdfLoader.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var customWebView = Element as PdfWebView;
                Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;    
                
           
    Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url={0}", customWebView.Uri.ToString()));          
   
                
            }

        }
    }
}
```

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        
     <local:PdfWebView 
            Uri="{Binding xxx}"
            Source="{Binding xxx}"  //set them as same value
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HeightRequest="300"
            WidthRequest="300"
            x:Name="pdf_Webview"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: You can directly open it on a webview

Comment: I checked the link on the end of the question, what is `Control` on that answer? I have added a webview on my xaml and set source of webview as pdfurl, but pdf not loading.

Comment: Share your sample .

Comment: sample project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KoAqfxOurwzL9RHsmUoJ3cwEbph0Tve8
I have added both options in sample, webview option is working in ios and not in android, device.openuri working in android not in ios.

Comment: Getting **System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203745/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-lucas-zhang-msft).

Comment: Yes, Sorry for the late response, my solution suddenly shows some errors. So I Run clean and rebuild couple of times.